# Jump to a specific carousel slide based on something other than position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to achieve a way, where I can jump to a specific carousel slide after clicking a button. Now, I know you can do that using indices of specific slides, however, because the content of the slides won't always be in the same order, indices don't solve my issue.

I've looked at Owl carousel, and it seems to be possible to achieve this with it, but I'm limited with the libraries I can use and would much prefer to avoid it.

Is there a way to jump to a specific slide using something else, like an id or an attribute I could set, preferably by using JQuery, JS or HTML, without any additional libraries?

Comment: The best way forward would be to determine a way to calculate the index of the slide you want to target, then use that to set the active slide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible by adding an id to the slide you want to switch to. Once you've done that you can simply do the following inside your click handler:

```
$('.carousel-item').removeClass('active'); //make all slides inactive
$('#your_id').addClass('active'); //activate the slide you want
```

The only problem with that approach is that the indicators (these are optional so you might just want to not include them) will not be updated and show the wrong slide as active.